# PHP sessionID changing between pages

Tags: php, session

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I want to use sessionvariables in PHP. I use session_start() on top of every page (no browseroutput before this).

I noticed that I lost the session between my pages. So I checked the sessionId. And it changed, so thats the problem.

But I also have a sessionbased login in php on the same website/domain and this works fine! And when I'm logged in, the sessionvariables on the other two pages also work fine! The sessionId stays the same then.

I looked for a difference. I found one: the session for the login is initiated from a page located at mydomain.com/php/ and my other pages are in the root.

So I tested my use of the sessionvariables with the two pages inside mydomain.com/php and now it works fine for those two!

But how is that possible? and how can I fix this so my pages in the root can also use sessionvariables without losing the session between the pages in the root?

Used code on both pages:

```
<?php session_start();

echo session_id();

?>
```

path = '/' 
domain = ' ' and I tried '.mydomain.com' but didn't work.

save_path = 'C:\Windows\temp'.

I checked, but 'C:\Windows\temp' is not writable, could that be the problem? But how is it possible that my login function still works? And my two other testpages?

Also on page reload, the sessionid changes.

I changed the PHP version from 7.09 to 5.60 and now it works fine! What has changed in php sessions since PHP 5.60? I can't figure it out. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Assuming you're using cookie based sessions; check the `path` component in `session_set_cookie_params()` - it should be `/` if you want it to be domain-wide. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: would you please show your code ? your sessionid changes that means you are overwrite the sessionid in any page

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: I added the code

Comment: @CD001: the path is set to '/', I checked.